# Quarkus encapsulation behavior

Tags: spring-boot, quarkus

I have this class:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class BookService {
    public boolean doorClosed;

    public boolean isDoorClosed() {
        return doorClosed;
    }
}
```

And I have this test class:

```
@QuarkusTest
public class BookServiceTest {

    @Inject BookService bookService;
       
    @Test
    public void testBookServiceDoor() throws InterruptedException {
        bookService.doorClosed=true;
        assertTrue(bookService.doorClosed);
        assertTrue(bookService.isDoorClosed());
    }
}
```

I am surprised that the last test assertion fails. The first passes but the last fails. It almost seems like that the getter/setters are using different variables than the one I am accessing directly.

I did the same test with Spring Boot and got the two assertions passing:

```
@Service
public class BookService {

    public boolean doorClosed;

    public boolean isDoorClosed() {
        return doorClosed;
    }
}
```

And the test:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class BookServiceTest {

    @Autowired BookService bookService;
       
    @Test
    public void testBookServiceDoor() throws InterruptedException {
        bookService.doorClosed=true;
        assertTrue(bookService.doorClosed);
        assertTrue(bookService.isDoorClosed());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `@ApplicationScoped` annotation makes the class a *normal scoped* bean. This means that the container never injects an actual instance of the class; instead, you get a proxy that will lookup the correct instance on each method invocation.

This is most commonly useful for example with `@RequestScoped` beans, where you get a single proxy, which will dispatch method invocations to instances that belong to the "current request" (typically an HTTP request). However, there are good reasons why you might want this for application scoped beans as well (e.g. when you want lazy initialization).

The rule is: never access fields directly on normal scoped beans, only call methods.

If you want, you can make the class `@Singleton`. That is a *pseudo scope*, and you get no proxy, you get the actual instance that you can work with directly.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Does this happen with any other framework? I could not reproduce this with Spring. No matter what the implementation does, semantically, this doesn't seem right. The contract of the accessors is that they should return the value of the field they allow access to. No?  The fact that panache promotes using the field directly is quite in contradiction to that rule.

Comment: Spring does the same thing under certain circumstances (for example, Spring also has request-scoped beans). If you want the Spring behavior, use `@Singleton` instead of `@ApplicationScoped`. And the problem isn't in calling accessors, it's in accessing fields directly -- you don't access the field of the bean instance, you access the field of the proxy. The accessor, on the other hand, is forwarded to the bean instance, which is a different object. Finally, JPA entities (including Panache) are usually not beans (same as in Spring), so I think you're comparing the incomparable there.